# Angular form Save-Saved

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-form

I want to change the text of my form button from Save to Saved when the form was saved successfully.

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="saveForm()">
  <!-- some input text fields here -->
  <button type="submit">{{buttonText}}</button>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.buttonText = 'Save';
$scope.saveForm = function() {
  //save operation here
  $scope.buttonText = 'Saved';
  $scope.myForm.$setPristine();
};
```

This is working perfectly but how can I reset the button to 'Save' when the user changes values in the form to save it another time? One possibility that comes to my mind is a $watch on the pristine state of the form but I think there are better solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage ng-change event handlers on form items and modify state of the button there.

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="saveForm()">
  <input type="text" ng-model="foo" ng-change="formChanged()" />
  <button type="submit">{{buttonText}}</button>
</form>
```

and in your controller:

```
$scope.formChanged= function() {
  $scope.buttonText = 'Save';
  //any other logic necessary
};
```

This is much lighter than using a watch and you can be a lot smarter about the actions you take (eg. what changed, if it returned to original value etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can, for example, add a custom watch on your scope properties that when one of them changes you reset the text of the button.

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="saveForm()">
  <input type="text" ng-model="foo" />
  <button type="submit">{{buttonText}}</button>
</form>
```

.

```
$scope.$watch('foo', function(){
    $scope.buttonText = 'save';
});
```

You can also use ng-change on each input to call a function that resets the text but would not have my preference since it goes by the cost of maintainability I guess. On the other hand a watch may be a bit expensive.

To make the watch bit easier you should nest your model properties on one object and use $watchCollection (since 1.2)

Comment: Yes this is similar to what I thought of. But I want to use $watch only when there is not other way around..

Comment: I think your stuck with the watch. I'd go with $watchCollection. See my edit.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Guess there is not a better solution than ng-changed or $watch.

Answer (score 0):

You can call ng-change in your input field and write a function to reset it again.

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="foo" ng-change="buttonText ='save'"/>
```